# Jquery accordion not displaying content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the following code, in an attempt to achieve an accordion on my site, however it is not working - can anyone please advise as to why (both the js and css are referenced in the head of my web page)?

HTML:

```
   <dl class="accordion">
     <dt>Answer 1</dt>
     <dd>Details of the answer go here...</dd>
     </dl>
     <dl class="accordion">
     <dt>Answer 2</dt>
     <dd>Details of the answer go here...</dd>
     </dl>
```

CSS:

```
    .accordion { margin: 0 0 30px; border-top: 1px solid #DDD; border-right: 1px solid #DDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }

    .accordion dt { border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD; }

    .accordion dd { display: none; padding: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD; }

    .accordion dt { cursor: pointer; padding: 8px 15px; margin: 0; }

    .accordion dt:before { content: "\25B6"; padding-right: 5px; }

    .accordion dt.accordion-active:before { content: "\25BE"; padding-right: 5px; }

    .accordion dt.accordion-active:hover { cursor: default; }
```

JS:

```
 (function($) {
    //Hide all panels
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    //Show first panel
    $('.accordion > dd:first-of-type').show();
    //Add active class to first panel 
    $('.accordion > dt:first-of-type').addClass('accordion-active');
    //Handle click function
    jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
      //this clicked panel
      $this = $(this);
    //the target panel content
      $target = $this.next(); 

       //Only toggle non-displayed 
       if(!$this.hasClass('accordion-active')){
          //slide up any open panels and remove active class
          $this.parent().children('dd').slideUp();

          //remove any active class
         jQuery('.accordion > dt').removeClass('accordion-active');
          //add active class
          $this.addClass('accordion-active');
          //slide down target panel
         $target.addClass('active').slideDown();

      } 

    return false;
 });

 })(jQuery)
```

;

Comment: It is not going inside the if condition, where you are checking - !$this.hasClass('accordion-active')

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
  //Hide all panels
  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    //the target panel content
    $target = $this.next();

    if ($target.hasClass("in")) {
      $target.slideUp();
      $target.removeClass("in");
    } else {
      jQuery('.accordion > dd').removeClass("in");
      $target.addClass("in");

      jQuery('.accordion > dd').slideUp();
      $target.slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

Adding a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPOO1uzvlMZeL7bGfQNc?p=preview) link to manage selected arrow.

Comment: Added a plunker to manage the arrow for active plunker :)
Nice code!

Comment: Thanks for the response - can this be used in a .js file? Or does it need to be included in the page body. I currently have 'accordion.js' added to the site and it's still not working...

Comment: This should be inside script tag in body or can be in directly added in JS file(Make sure to add reference of that JS file in your HTML) as well.
Can you elaborate on what is not working and if there is any error in console?

Comment: Have a look at the link in this answer as well.

Comment: I've included the above in a js file and referenced it in the head of my document after the jquery library reference and it's not working, very odd! This is within Magento. The file is definitely there as I can see it on page source and the CSS is referenced and working too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/39vytpz87X0qU4n5gP0J?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <style>
        .accordion {
            margin: 0 0 30px;
            border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
            border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
            border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .accordion dt {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
        }

        .accordion dd {
            display: none;
            padding: 20px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
        }

        .accordion dt {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 8px 15px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .accordion dt:before {
            content: "\25B6";
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .accordion dt.accordion-active:before {
            content: "\25BE";
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .accordion dt.accordion-active:hover {
            cursor: default;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <dl class="accordion">
        <dt>Answer 1</dt>
        <dd>Details of the answer go here...</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="accordion">
        <dt>Answer 2</dt>
        <dd>Details of the answer go here...</dd>
    </dl>

    <script>
        (function($) {
            //Hide all panels
            var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
            //Show first panel
            // commenting this
            // $('.accordion > dd:first-of-type').show();
            //Add active class to first panel 
            // $('.accordion > dt:first-of-type').addClass('accordion-active');
            //Handle click function
            jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
                //this clicked panel
                $this = $(this);
                //the target panel content
                $target = $this.next();

                //Only toggle non-displayed 
                if (!$this.hasClass('accordion-active')) {
                    // hide all dd's
                    $('.accordion > dd').hide();
                    //slide up any open panels and remove active class
                    $this.parent().children('dd').slideUp();

                    //remove any active class
                    jQuery('.accordion > dt').removeClass('accordion-active');
                    //add active class
                    $this.addClass('accordion-active');
                    //slide down target panel
                    $target.addClass('active').slideDown();

                }

                return false;
            });

        })(jQuery)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```